Can't download multiple files simultaneously, despite following OneDrive's documentation
I wish to download Marathon Phoenix soundtrack.  The "upmastered FLAC" download link goes to a publicly shared OneDrive folder.
As documented below, each individual file has a "download" option.  However, when I select more than one file, the "Download" option goes away.
How can I reasonably download all of these files, using the OneDrive website?

Download files and folders from OneDrive or SharePoint - Microsoft Support
Applies To [...] OneDrive (home or personal)

On your OneDrive, SharePoint in Microsoft 365, SharePoint Server Subscription Edition, or SharePoint Server 2019 website, select the files or folders you want to download.

In the top navigation, select Download. (You can also right-click the file, photo, or folder, and select Download.)




The first step of the instructions says: "on your OneDrive".
To download multiple files, you must be logged in to OneDrive with your Microsoft account.
If you do not already have a Microsoft Account, you can create one for free.
Note: The website asks you to enter your Microsoft password.  How do you know the website is safe?
